# Wildcard vhost subdomains with 301 redirect

Tags: apache-2.2, debian, web-server, virtualhost

At the moment I create a .htaccess file which redirects non-existent sub domains to the root URL. 
E.g

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin www@example.co.uk
    ServerName example.co.uk
    ServerAlias www.example.co.uk
    DocumentRoot /var/www/example/public

    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/example.co.uk-error.log
    LogLevel warn
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/example.co.uk-access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

# Redirect for non existent subdomains
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin www@example.co.uk
    ServerAlias *.example.co.uk
    DocumentRoot /var/www/example/redirect
</VirtualHost>
```

**/var/www/example/redirect/.htaccess**

```
Redirect 301 / http://www.example.co.uk
```

Is there a way I can do this all in Apache? I want this to be search engine friendly by redirecting with the 301 code to tell them that the subdomains doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Redirect Directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect) is described thus,

> Description:  Sends an external redirect asking the client to fetch a different URL
>
> Syntax:   Redirect [status] URL-path URL
>
> **Context:    server config, *virtual host*, directory, .htaccess**
>
> Override: FileInfo
>
> Status:   Base Module:    mod_alias

Bold emphasis mine.  You should be able to put the redirect into the VirtualHost section, without the need for the .htaccess.

If you want to say the domain doesn't exist, you should return 410 (gone), although I'm not sure of your intent.  302 might be sufficient.